# Inaccurate display URL

Tags: admob

I am trying to advertise our app via admob but my add is rejected the third time. Disapproval Reason: Inaccurate display URL.
My application is a windows phone game. According to this article https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3086746?hl=en my URL for windows phone apps must be constructed in the way:

```
 www.windowsphone.com/<language>-<country>/store/app/<app-name>/<app-id>
```

Here is the url, which I entered in the admob:

```
 www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/hungy/36319ee3-a15c-43cc-af5d-e02398c6fe84
```

Can anybody please suggest what is wrong with the entered url?

Answer (score 0):

I think they do not like changing the page address in the transition.

[image]

Try this:

> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/games/hungy/9nblggh1hwv0

Well, you can always write to support.

But I think that you should add more good reviews before advertising campaign )

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I tried https://www.microsoft.com... URL too, but got the same result - Inaccurate URL :(
To be honest - I tried to write to admob support, but was not able to find their support email address after few minutes googling.
Any way I`ll try to write them. 
By the way to get reviews (good or bad) I need more users. To get more users I need to advertise the app :)) closed cycle

Comment: I mean: ask friends to set reviews.
Have you tried the link as I have written or not "https"? I was wrong: the protocol can not write. AdMob support: https://support.google.com/admob#topic=2740022

Comment: Yes, but admob automatically sets the protocol when saving the form